# Why can import not be resolved?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, windowbuilder

I have the following import in 2 identical programs (ok, maybe they weren't identical. They looked identical, but I forgot that the first was created with WindowBuilderPro):

`import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;`

In the first program it's ok. In the second, Eclipse can't resolve it. The build path is identical. Any ideas why?

Comment: Not my downvote, but you probably are missing a library on your classpath.

Comment: add missing library in class path

Comment: is that library present at that location

Comment: It seems to me it's not present in either program: but the first one runs fine, as I said

Comment: I'll just check it again

Comment: Just worked out the answer: the first was created with WindowBuilder Pro, the second without.

Comment: check eclipse error view, to see what eclipse is saying as cause.

Comment: How? you mean the box that comes up when I hover over the error? By the way, I already worked out the answer: the first was created with WindowBuilderPro, the second without, but I'm interested to find out whether I know about Eclipse error view

Comment: 3 downvotes without any explanation!?  That's not fair.

Comment: ha ha..........that's what i thought +1 for being on my side: no, to be fair though, it's their prerogative

Answer (score 0):

Just worked out the answer: the first was created with WindowBuilderPro, the second without. WindowBuilderPro inserted the import automatically. Why this means the first program doesn't work and the second does, I don't know, so this doesn't answer the question 'Why can the import not be resolved?' fully, but it does show how to get from a program which has an error to one which doesn't (use WindowBuilderPro), which is fine for me for the time being.

Comment: Firstly, you never specified in the question about `WindowBuilder` in your question. Also, how did using it not give the error and not using it, gave the error. Don't you need to mention it in your answer, so that later anybody else referring your answer can know about it?!

Comment: The reason I never mentioned it in my question is because it hadn't occurred to me that this would cause the import to be unresolved, but I take your second point. +1 for useful feedback

Comment: For me there was a difference! When creating with WindowBuilder and using FocusTraversalOnArray, it adds a package to my project... Copy that package and you should be fine...